# UFT - Open the AUT page in compatibility view

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, qtp, ie8-compatibility-mode, browser-automation

I need to open my URL in compatibility mode i.e. in IE8 mode having an IE9.

The AUT won´t work in IE9 and the developer is OK with that.

I have thought of trying to impregnate the following HTML (no brackets included):

```
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"
```

but not sure how to do it via VBScript and give the order at the moment of opening the URL.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just configure IE´s settings so it always opens the sites you are interested in in compatibility mode?

Comment: I could, but we are talking many computers and many of them formatted every now and then...

Comment: You could script (or registry-patch) the IE setting reconfiguration into the "start my AUT" test, and thus re-do it whenever you start the AUT. Then, it will always be there, no matter what happened to the PC at hand. (Yes, this is ugly.)

Comment: OK... any idea how to do this?

Comment: http://www.danielclasson.com/guide-how-to-force-specific-sites-to-always-run-in-compatibility-view-using-group-policy/

Comment: Or check the first answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456490/how-to-set-feature-browser-emulation-to-ie8-mode

Comment: There´s also an IE7 sample code snippet in http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/code/442963/make-the-webbrowser-control-give-you-the-installed-ie-version-rendering, this might be a good starting point.

Comment: And to complete my comment spam wave, here is the official bible to the browser emulation feature control feature: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation

In summary, I get the impression that you have to add a key for each process hosting the browser control. Which one might that be? Since you are using IE, not an IE browser control-hosting app, I´m not sure if this works. I´d try specifying IE´s executable for the process name. Hths.

Comment: promising. especially the Group Policy one. Of course it would depend on the Admin rights I have to do this. Thanks!