# Browser emulation to the highest possible version of IE installed

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-8, vb6, webbrowser-control

In my vb6 application I have used webbrowser control in which online payment gateway website is loaded and it requires IE 8 and above. But even if IE 8 is installed the webbrowser control renders it in IE7 mode. It can be solved by using [Browser emulation registry](http://www.pedautreppe.com/post/How-can-we-render-CSS3-in-a-WebBrowser-Control-.aspx)  and I was able to solve it.

But now I have set value to 8888(Webpages are displayed in IE8 Standards mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive) . But if I do this even if PC has IE 9, 10 or 11 then it will be rendered in IE8 mode. But I think it will be better if the webbrowser control is rendered in highest version of IE installed in a PC, instead of fixing it to IE8 mode.

So how I can make Browser emulation to set to highest version of IE installed in PC?

Answer (score 3):

This is not easy, because there is no value for "edge" rendering. You could **get IE version** from registry

```
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\svcVersion or Version
```

...try both keys, newer versions IE use *svcVersion*, older *Version*. Then **set the appropriate value** ([see msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx)) in the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key.

This solution has one big disadvantage: your program must have **permissions** for writing in registry. It is better to do it during installation, this is the correct way (however the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION value is not updated in case of upgrading IE).

Comment: `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` basicly does the same *and* is writable for regular users.

Comment: @wqw there exists different value for each IE version for FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION. But i found that if i put value 11001 (value for ie 11) in a PC having IE9 it worked and my error of website loading solved. So is it allowed give IE 11 value for IE 9 pc and it works like highest possible version?

Comment: Well, the value 11001 could be the right way, but it is an undocumented feature. Double check all tests. - Note: In my code I had serious problems with DOM manipulation from VB6 code. For example _Document.All.Item("id1") Is Nothing_ worked well in IE7 emulation, but not higher. Test carefully your code.

Comment: For anyone interested, here's how to set the emulation version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456490

Answer (score 0):

Just put a big number like "11111111" as the value of FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION key. It will then take up the latest IE version installed in the system.

Comment: 11001 (0x2AF9 Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11 edge mode, regardless of the declared !DOCTYPE directive. Failing to declare a !DOCTYPE directive causes the page to load in Quirks.