# Forcing Enterprise Mode in IE when embedding IE window in Windows application

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a Windows application that embeds an Internet Explorer frame/window. This works fine, however, the Enterprise Mode in IE is not being used, even though the domain of the called web site is listed in the domains for which IE should use the Enterprise Mode. (Note: When I call the same URL directly within IE, then the Enterprise Mode is correctly used.)

Unfortunately I neither can access the registry on the client machines, nor can I change group policies or something like that. Now, is there any way to force that Enterprise Mode when I call an URL in an embedded window?

Comment: You can set the FEATURE_CONTROL_BROWSER_EMULATION of your windows form executable to a lower value. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456490/how-to-set-feature-browser-emulation-to-ie8-mode. OR (if your win exe already has IE11 emulation. (check by alert(document.documentMode)) you can use a meta x-ua in the top web form to a lower emulation mode (IE10)...child iframes inherit the documentMode of the parent.

Comment: MSDN blog - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/